# Format lubridate duration column for axis labelling

Tags: r, time, ggplot2, lubridate

I want to plot data containing numbers and durations. For the transformation of the character vector I chose the `lubridate` package. Unfortunately, the duration is always printed in seconds on the x axis:

```
set.seed(20161027)
a <- c("00:30:45", "00:59:07", "01:08:30", "02:10:09", "02:20:53")
b <- rnorm(n = 5)
example <- data.frame(a, b)
# This is what I want
ggplot(data = example, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
geom_point()
library(lubridate)
a <- hms(a)
a <- as.duration(a)
example <- data.frame(a, b)
ggplot(data = example, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
geom_point()
```

This is how I want it to look like.
[image: correct]

This is how it currently looks.
[image: wrong]
Is there a `lubridate` way to format the time to a prettier format? Or do I need to preserve the character vector for axis labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @HubertL's solution is good enough, but if you insist on using `lubridate`, you can try

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(20161027)
a <- c("00:30:45", "00:59:07", "01:08:30", "02:10:09", "02:20:53")
b <- rnorm(5)
example <- data.frame(a=hms(a), b=b)

ggplot(data = example, aes(x = a$hour + a$minute / 60 + a$second / 60^2, y = b)) +
    geom_point() + 
    scale_x_continuous(name="a", 
                       breaks=c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2), 
                       labels=c("00:30", "01:00", "01:30", "02:00"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you'd want to do this with `lubridate`. By using `as.POSIXct`:

```
a <- as.POSIXct(c("00:30:45", "00:59:07", "01:08:30", "02:10:09", "02:20:53"),
                format="%H:%M:%S")
b <- rnorm(n = 5)
example <- data.frame(a, b)
ggplot(data = example, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Even though I will use to this solution @kitman0804 provided the answer to the question. I was using `lubridate` because the duration class felt like a better representation of the data (because I do not have dates). I guess it is not worth the extra mile in my case.